# CarPlay - Show Now Playing screen in iOS 13

Tags: ios, mpnowplayinginfocenter, carplay, mpremotecommandcenter, mpplayablecontentdelegate

My app is already the current "now playing app" on the phone (i.e. all the required info are provided to `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`) and it correctly shows in the lock screen, with artist name, track title, artwork image, etc.

According to the docs, populating `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo` and adding the proper target/actions to `MPRemoteCommandCenter` **should be enough** to make sure your app is invoked in CarPlay when the user taps on the `Now Playing` icon.

On iOS 14 I managed to achieve the above by pushing `CPNowPlayingTemplate` to the stack, thanks to some clever tricks I found [in this article](https://medium.com/br-next/launching-br-radio-on-carplay-audio-8baab824b932).

On iOS 13 though, where everything is based on the dreadful `MPPlayableContentManager` APIs and **no `CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate` methods are invoked for audio-based apps** I simply cannot find a way to detect if/when the Now Playing screen will be displayed.

`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` and `MPRemoteCommandCenter` are correctly configured - as said above - but my app is not picked up when tapping the Now Playing icon in CarPlay on iOS 13.

I thought [this API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpplayablecontentmanager/1649434-nowplayingidentifiers) would help me but I couldn't figure out how (it always returns an empty array).

The only workaround seems to be adding `<key>UIBrowsableContentSupportsImmediatePlayback</key><true/>` to your `Info.plist`: Now Playing gets correctly displayed but it starts playback immediately, which is not what I want.

Can anyone provide a working solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On pre-iOS 14 CarPlay we are setting the now playing identifiers (in our case just one since we don't have a playlist) after initiating playing:

- `MPPlayableContentManager.shared().nowPlayingIdentifiers = ["Some Id"]`
- This id should be the same id as the `MPContentItem` that initiated the playback (and has `isPlayable` set to `true`

Comment: Thank you ever so much, it works perfectly! I hope you agree that developing for CarPlay on iOS 14 is a much more joyful experience though 

Comment: Yeah definitely! But we can't drop iOS 12/13 support just yet 